# Set Combobox column Selected Value

Tags: winforms, telerik, radgridview

```
GridViewComboBoxColumn Currency = (GridViewComboBoxColumn)dgv_AddJournal.Columns["Currencry"];
Currency.DataSource = ListCurency;
Currency.DisplayMember = "NameArabic";
Currency.ValueMember = "ID";
```

How To set Selected Value `RadGrid` i can't find  `Currency.SelectedValue` in page Load

Comment: Hi! If I understand you correctly then you want to set a default selected value when the page has loaded?

Comment: Is this a winforms or ASP question?